# Macro Variables within email template in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have the following code:

```
%let host = HostThatSendsEmail;
%let todayDate = &SYSDATE9;
signon host;
rsubmit;


filename mail email to =    ("PersonGettingEmail")
        from=   "PersonSendingEmail"
        SUBJECT="Today is &todayDate";

data _null_;
    file mail;
    put 'Dear All';
    put 'Today is &todayDate';
run;

endrsubmit;
```

The macro date does not get inputed into the email when the code is run. The resulting email should read:

Dear all
Today is 29Mar12.

Instead it reads:

Dear all
Today is &TodayDate

Is there some piece of code I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created the macro locally...but then you signed on to a remote host. Your remote session of SAS doesn't know about the macro on the local host.

Using [%SYSLPUT](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/connref/61908/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002590516.htm) is one way to solve this problem [(Another link)](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001221974.htm).

Place this code between the SIGNON and the RSUBMIT

```
 %SYSLPUT TODAYDATE = &todayDate;
```

If you had a large number of macro vars that you wanted available on the remote host. You could write them to a data set and use [PROC UPLOAD](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/connref/61908/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002558373.htm) to move the data set to the remote host.

Answer (score 5):

Try double quotes in the datastep.  Macrovariables will not resolve in single quotes.

Comment: It is true that you need double quotes to force the macro var to resolve.

Comment: They will resolve inside single-quotes if you wrap it in a `%BQUOTE('&VAR')`